# How to get PRIMARY KEY ID of objects in DataBase -android sqlite 3

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-maps, android-sqlite

I want to get a primary key of a saved object in a table in database I wrote a class to handle my database I want to add a function to it for getting the Id (I tried to give id to objects manually it didn't go well so I prefer the primary key id)so how should this function look like?and also if u see a thing that needs changing in my code please let me know.

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static int _ID =0;
private int ID =0;
private ArrayList<marker_model> markerList=new ArrayList<>();

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, Constans.TABLE_NAME, null, Constans.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+Constans.TABLE_NAME+
                 " ("+Constans.MARKER_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
 Constans.MARKER_TITLE+" TEXT, " +Constans.MARKER_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT ,"+Constans.My_MARKER_ID+" INT );");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Constans.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void AddMarker(marker_model marker){

    marker.set_Id(_ID);
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(Constans.MARKER_TITLE,marker.getTitle());
    values.put(Constans.My_MARKER_ID,marker.get_Id());
    values.put(Constans.MARKER_DESCRIPTION,marker.getDescription());

    db.insert(Constans.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "AddMarker: Successfully added to DB");

    _ID++;
}

public ArrayList<marker_model> getMarkers(){
    markerList.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.query(Constans.TABLE_NAME
            ,new String[]{Constans.My_MARKER_ID,Constans.MARKER_TITLE,
                    Constans.MARKER_DESCRIPTION},null,null,null,null,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            ID=0;
            marker_model model=new marker_model();
            model.set_Id(_ID);
            model.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constans.MARKER_DESCRIPTION)));
            model.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constans.MARKER_TITLE)));

            markerList.add(model);
            ID++;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return markerList;
}

public int getMarkerPrimaryId(Marker marker){

}


}
```

Comment: That's one of the fields in the model object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get the **_id** (the primary key) from the database and that marker is an instance of a marker_model object AND that
marker_model has methods `getTitle` and `getDescription` that return a string with the respective values, then something along the lines of the following would work.

```
public long getMarkerPrimaryId(Marker marker){

     long rv = 0;
     SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
     String[] columns = new String[]{Constans.My_MARKER_ID};
     String whereclause = Constans.MARKER_TITLE + "=?" +
         Constans.MARKER_DESCRIPTION + "=?";
     String[] whereargs = new String[]{
         marker.getTitile,
         marker.getDescription  
     }
     Cursor cursor = db.query(Constans.TABLE_NAME,
         columns,
         whereclause,
         whereargs,
         null,null,null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        rv = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constans.My_MARKER_ID);
    }
    cursor.close;
    db.close;
    return rv;
}
```

However, if your issue is that `getMarkers` is not setting the **Id** member appropriately (i.e. to match the id in the database), then changing `model.set_Id(_ID);`

to

```
model.set_Id(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constans.My_MARKER_ID));
```

would suffice.

If your expectation is that an automatically generated incrementing **_id** is to be used the `addMarker` is a little flawed. Simply by removing the line `values.put(Constans.My_MARKER_ID,marker.get_Id());` will result in _id being automatically generated (which how _id's tend to be used).

The following (BACKGROUND paragraph mostly) explains much about automatically generated unique identifiers (even though it is about AUTOINCREMENT you likely DO NOT want to code AUTOINCREMENT).

Id suggest that rather than :-

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
        ...
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

using :-
         while (cursor.moveToNext() {
             ....
         }

is simpler (*a cursor, when created, will be positioned to before the first row* (*`moveToPosition(-1)` has the same effect*) , `moveToNext()` will move to the first row the first time, if there are no rows the loop will not be entered (you may wish to consider this and the state of returned `markerlist`)).

Note! the above has been written without testing, so there may be the odd mistake.